# Subdomain not working in route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a domain (lets call it mydomain.com). I want to create a subdomain and point it to an ec2 instance. I don't want a load balancer in front of it because it's just a demo instance. Using route 53, I created an A record for demoapi.mydomain.com and put the associated elastic ip address as the record value. The TTL is 300 and it's been over 24 hours and the subdomain still doesn't resolve. What am I missing? Here's what my setup looks like (with a different ip obviously):

[image: my setup]

Why does this not resolve? I'm sure I have the right IP address because I can get the responses I expect with it.

Comment: There's nothing complicated about what you're doing here. Are you sure that your EC2 instance is expecting to accept traffic that has `demoapi.mydomain.com` as its host name? If you ping or dig the domain does it resolve to your public IP?

Comment: If I try and go to the name with a browser I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. If I go to just the IP I get a 404 but that is provided by the server itself since it doesn't have anything that responds on the root level route. Does it need to respond to a root level request for the DNS to mark it as valid or something?

Comment: This is a record you created in the same hosted zone that your domain is already using, in Route 53?  Or did you create a different hosted zone for the subdomain?

Comment: This is the same hosted zone. I have a sub domain demo.my domain.com in the same hosted zone that points to an s3 bucket and that works fine.